# Dynamic text score

Tags: text, dynamic, boolean

I have character picking coins (total 6) correctly displayed in dynamic
 text and am trying to have another dynamic text show 120 credits when all 6 coins are picked. 
To do that I created a boolean  attached to the first dynamic text. The problem is that the text with the 120 credits 
needs to show on frame 25 and the coins and the other action are on frame 10.

```
 if(coinCollected == false){
    if(player.hitTestObject(back.other.oncoin)){
        coinCollected = true;
        score++;
   }
 scoreCounter.text = "Score:  " + score ;
 }
 var coinspicked:Boolean = false;

  if (score == 6){

coinspicked = true;

}
```

On frame 25 I have

```
 if (coinspicked = true){
 trace("120 credits");
 txtfield.text = "120";
 }
 else {
txtfield.text = "60";
trace("60 credits");
 }
```

And it does not work for some reason, it's showing me 120 credits in any case.  I would appreciate any guidance Thank you.

Comment: The opening and closing braces in your first code snippet do not match. Should this not be the case in this language? (Whatever it is. Maybe you should add a tag for it.)

Comment: You are right!.... I did miss 2 brackets, because I had another non-relevant code that I removed.... sorry I just changed it.